# How do you properly set up a thread to be GC'd in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, garbage-collection

I was wondering how to set up a created thread to be GC'd. I made a simple multithreaded server to accept connections from the client, but each time a client connects, the memory usage grows by about 80k... understandable. Problem is that I don't know how to come back down from that quick growth after the client and server disconnect.

Here's the main class that sets up the thread:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   try {
      serverSock= new ServerSocket(9999);
   } catch (IOException e1) {
      e1.printStackTrace();
   }

   while (true){
      try {
         Thread t = new server(serverSock.accept());
         t.start();
         t = null;
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

And here is the basic server thread:

```
public class server extends Thread {
     private Socket serverSocket = null;
     public static String command = null;

     public server(Socket serverSocket2) {
      super("server");
      serverSocket = serverSocket2;
     }

     @Override
     public void run(){
      BufferedReader fromClient = null;
      PrintStream toClient = null;
      String line = null;
      String[] user = new String[2];

      try {
       serverSocket.setSoTimeout(10000);
       fromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serverSocket.getInputStream()));
       toClient = new PrintStream(serverSocket.getOutputStream());
       System.out.println("Got connection");
                System.out.println("Terminating server");
       fromClient.close();
       toClient.close();
       serverSocket.close()
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
       System.out.println("Connection established, but timeout on" +
         " message recieve may have occured");
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
}
```

Now, how exactly would I allow this thread to just... die and go away, rather than causing the memory leak that is currently occurring?

Also, I'm new to Java - never mind using threads, so if it's obvious, please try to be nice about it. Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Setting `t` to `null` has no effect at all, since immediately after that statement the block ends and `t` goes out of scope. @Pete: So what if you set `t` to `null` while the thread runs? Nothing bad will happen to the thread.

Comment: I was under the impression that unless we retained a pointer to the thread subclass, it could be GC'd after it went out of scope (like any other object).  I guess... not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A GC only runs when it needs to, it doesn't appear to need to so objects/thread which could be cleaned are not.  This doesn't mean there is a memory leak. It means the memory isn't needed.

BTW: You shouldn't extend Thread directly. Instead I suggest you use an Executors.newCachedThreadPool(). This will handle short lived Threads much more efficiently.

Also when ServerSocket throws an exception, this is not recoverable.  It does mean that once it fails, it will fail endlessly.  If an exception is thrown, its generally a bad idea to print it an continue as if it didn't happen.

A shorter version of your main which won't fail endlessly is

```
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket serverSock = new ServerSocket(9999);
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    while (true)
      es.submit(new ClientHandler(serverSock.accept()));
  }
}
class ClientHandler implements Runnable {
  private final Socket socket;
  public ClientHandler(Socket socket) { this.socket = socket; }

  public void run()  {
    while(true) {
       // do something with the socket. 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Since D4N14L's new to Java, you need to point out that, rather than extend Thread directly, he should implement [`Runnable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) instead.

Comment: @R. Bemrose, I was going to suggest Callable<Void>, but Runnable is a better choice, thank you.

Comment: @R. Bemrose: Yes, I did have Runnable implemented in an earlier version, so I was just experimenting... just happened to post the code that extended thread. Thanks though.

Comment: That Executors.newCachedThreadPool() idea was very helpful. I'm already liking this community, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

1. How do you know there's a memory leak? It doesn't look like there's a leak to me
2. You don't need to do anything. The garbage collector is always running and it doesn't [differentiate] between objects referenced from a thread or not.
3. The only thing I see is, does `serverSock.accept()` block there? If not, you're just going to be creating threads as fast as that while loop runs. I'm not an expert here, so if the accept call blocks there before starting the thread then this could be ok.

Comment: `ServerSocket`'s [`accept`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept%28%29) blocks, yes.

Comment: I tweaked your answer to be more clear @Falmarri.  The GC certainly does care if an object is referenced, from a thread or not.  And frankly, everything is a thread anyway -- even the main thread.

Answer (score 2):

Between these two answers I'm not seeing this information.  GC will clean up threads that aren't active so if you let the thread exit the run() method it will be cleaned up by the GC.  Any memory referenced from that thread's stack will be cleaned up if it's inactive provided no other active thread references that memory from it's stack or no static root references it (Falmarri's answer point 2 is wrong on this or at least worded wrong).  GC is mostly hands free and automatic there's little work on your part to actually free up memory under normal circumstances.

Now the memory you see going up when the thread is created is different.  How are you measuring this 80K jump?  Are you using task manager, top, or some OS tool to see that bump?  The OS tools aren't much help in truly understanding what's going on internal to the JVM.  It might be freeing the memory internal to the JVM which OS tools can't see.  Reason being is Java is stingy with it's memory allocation.  Once it allocates more memory it keeps it even if it's not using it.  Reason is because the OS is slow to hand out memory to processes.  By holding onto it if it needs it again later, and statistics say yes it will, then it's faster to just hold onto it rather than freeing it.  Java will give memory back if the OS is low on memory or it is using very little memory out of the total.  That's seldom the case though.  Java is very efficient with it's memory allocation.

If you want to watch memory or see more detail I'd suggest using jconsole which ships with the JVM.  It will show you the internals of the JVM so you can see the total memory, heap, and 4 spaces (eden,survivor,tenured,Perm Generation) that make up the heap.  You can also see how much memory is occupied by your code in Code Gen space.  You can even see your active threads running in the process so if you have stuck threads you can diagnose this there too.  And you have an option to request GC so you can see how your app is using memory.

The whole point of this is if you think you have a leak you can start to make sense of it by using this tool.  It's super easy, really informative, and free.  If you have a leak you might need a memory profiler like jprofiler to tell you more details.

Comment: Thank you, that was very informative to a newbie like me. Yes, I was using the task manager... I will keep jConsole in mind for later problems.